# Location of Sphinx sources for my notes - WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree

Tags: python, python-sphinx, glob, toctree

**How can you fix the Sphinx's warning at the bottom?**

I am trying to have my Python notes in Sphinx.
I have my notes in separate files at the same directory level as the *index.rst*.

I get the following warnings after building HTML

**The warning**

```
/home/heo/S_codes/trig_functions.rst:: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
```

in

**The complete message when building**

```
sudo sphinx-build -b html ./ _build/html
Running Sphinx v0.6.2
loading pickled environment... done
building [html]: targets for 0 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 1 added, 2 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] trig_functions
/home/heo/S_codes/databooklet.rst:1: (WARNING/2) malformed hyperlink target.
/home/heo/S_codes/index.rst:11: (ERROR/3) Error in "toctree" directive:
invalid option block.

.. toctree::
   :numbered:
   :glob:
   *
   databooklet.rst
   trig_functions.rst


/home/heo/S_codes/trig_functions.rst:11: (ERROR/3) Unexpected indentation.
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... /home/heo/S_codes/databooklet.rst:: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
/home/heo/S_codes/trig_functions.rst:: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [100%] trig_functions
writing additional files... genindex search
copying static files... done
dumping search index... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded, 6 warnings.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you aware of Sphinx's documentation?  https://www.sphinx-doc.org

Specifically, read about the `toctree` directive: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-toctree

You can have as many files as you want.  Via `toctree` you can create a single document from many parts.

---

Please actually *read* this: http://sphinx.pocoo.org/concepts.html#document-names

> Since the reST source files can have
>   different extensions (some people like
>   .txt, some like .rst – the extension
>   can be configured with source_suffix)
>   and different OSes have different path
>   separators, Sphinx abstracts them: all
>   “document names” are relative to the
>   source directory, the extension is
>   stripped, and path separators are
>   converted to slashes. All values,
>   parameters and suchlike referring to
>   “documents” expect such a document
>   name.
>
> Examples for document names are `index`,
>   `library/zipfile`, or
>   `reference/datamodel/types`. Note that
>   there is no leading slash.

Since you globbed with `*`, you do not need to list your files.

If you want to list your files, please actually *read* and *follow* the above rules.